# how to make a delay for getting data in [(ngModel)]?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I display the data received from the server in  `[(ngModel)]` but since they do not come immediately, I get this error several times: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined". Then my data is displayed in the input field.

**How to make the data displayed only when it is received?**

**Template:**

```html
<form [formGroup]="angFormEd" novalidate>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="titleEd"  #titleEd
               [(ngModel)]="post.title"/>

        <input type="url" class="form-control" formControlName="urlEd" #urlEd pattern="https?://.+"
               title="Include http://" [(ngModel)]="post.url"/>
 
        <button (click)="updatePost(titleEd.value, urlEd.value)"  
                [disabled]=" angFormEd.invalid">
                btn btn-primary">Update Post</button>     
    </form>
```

**Component:**

```js
export class GalleryEditComponent implements OnInit {
    post: Picture;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
                private route: ActivatedRoute, private galleryService: GalleryService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.editPost();
    }

    editPost(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.galleryService.edit(params['id']).subscribe(res => {
                this.post = res;
            })
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Template Driven Form and Reactive Form which is a bad practice.

**[@Angular](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel)**

> Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event
>   with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and
>   will be removed in Angular v7.

Either go for `patchValue()` or `setValue()`
[`Updating Angular Forms with patchValue or setValue`](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value)

```
editPost(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.galleryService.edit(params['id']).subscribe(res => {
                this.post = res;
                this.angFormEd.setValue({titleEd:res.title,urlEd:res.url})
            })
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a condition like `*ngIf="post.url"` on your input, so that it only displays when it's loaded

Comment: Good, you're welcome :) don't forget to mark the question answered to close the topic :)